# Error with extract results from tomRun

Tags: matlab, simulink

i have an error with the function tomrun.I am running in the simulink in an embedeed blocks.This is the code

```
 Wnl = 1;
 dw = zeros (2,10);
 dw = [Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl;
 Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl];
 Prob = qpAssign(FF, S, Alpha, b_L(1:7), b_U(1:7), [], [], [], [],...
            [], [], [], [], [], [], []);
 Result = tomRun('qpSolve', Prob, 1)
 eml.extrinsic('extractResult');
 dwp = extractResult(Result)
 dwopt = [0 0];
 dwopt = dw
 wstart = [0.98 0.99];
 Wnlop = wstart + dwopt ;
%%function extract results
 function dww = extractResult(Result) 
 dww = Result.x_k;
 end
```

And i am taking this error
Embedded MATLAB Interface Error: Size mismatch for MATLAB expression 'dwp'. Expected = 1x2 Actual = 2x1 Block load_sharing (#19) While executing: none.

I tried to change the size but again i'm taking the same error,can someone help me?

Comment: Which line in the code is showing that error? I see only one assignment to dwp. So that should not throw a size mismatch error since it should take the size of whatever it is assigned to unless it is an input or output variable of your function.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code in an embedeed block

```
    function Wnlop  = loadsharing_Linearization_MPC(Wnlop3)%,e)

 Wnl = 1;
 dw = zeros (2,10);
 dw = [Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl;
 Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl Wnl];



FF = [ 945.8209  868.6367
       868.6367  797.7697];

S = [ -273.5275
 -251.1619];

Alpha = [ 0         0
    7.9634    7.3155
         0         0
    0.1303    0.1307
    7.9634    7.3155
   -7.9634   -7.3155
         0         0];

b_L = [29.1083   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583
   29.1083   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583
      -Inf   29.1540   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561
      -Inf   29.1561   27.1562   -0.0366   14.0596   14.0597   14.0597  -14.0597         0         0
   57.3266   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166
      -Inf         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583];

b_U =[ 29.2083   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583
   29.2083   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583
   31.6583   29.1540   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561   29.1561
   31.4061   29.1561   27.1562   -0.0366   14.0596   14.0597   14.0597  -14.0597         0         0
       Inf   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166   56.3166
    0.9700         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
       Inf   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583   28.1583];

   eml.extrinsic('extractResult');

eml.extrinsic('qpAssign','tomRun');
    Prob = qpAssign(FF, S, Alpha, b_L(1:7), b_U(1:7), [], [], [], [],...
            [], [], [], [], [], [], []);
 Result = tomRun('qpSolve', Prob, 1)
 eml.extrinsic('extractResult');
 dwp = extractResult(Result)
 dwopt = [0 0];
 dwopt = dw
 wstart = [0.98 0.99]
  Wnlop = wstart + dwopt ;
```